# sql data type to php data type in model

Tags: php, phalcon

When u retrieve data from database in model returns all values as string.

For example, if u load a model $user = User::findFirst(1), when u access to property $user->id its return a (string) "1".

I declared metadata in models to try to get a php types, but doesnt works:

```
public function metaData()
{
    return array(
        //Every column in the mapped table
        MetaData::MODELS_ATTRIBUTES => array(
            'id',  'email', 'password', 'created'
        ),

        //Every column part of the primary key
        MetaData::MODELS_PRIMARY_KEY => array(
            'id'
        ),

        //Every column that isn't part of the primary key
        MetaData::MODELS_NON_PRIMARY_KEY => array(
             'email', 'password', 'created'
        ),

        //Every column that doesn't allows null values
        MetaData::MODELS_NOT_NULL => array(
            'id',  'email', 'password', 'created'
        ),

        //Every column and their data types
        MetaData::MODELS_DATA_TYPES => array(
            'id' => Column::TYPE_INTEGER,
            'email' => Column::TYPE_VARCHAR,
            'password' => Column::TYPE_VARCHAR,
            'created' => Column::TYPE_INTEGER,
        ),

        //The columns that have numeric data types
        MetaData::MODELS_DATA_TYPES_NUMERIC => array(
            'id' => true,
            'year' => true,
        ),

        //The identity column, use boolean false if the model doesn't have
        //an identity column
        MetaData::MODELS_IDENTITY_COLUMN => 'id',

        //How every column must be bound/casted
        MetaData::MODELS_DATA_TYPES_BIND => array(
            'id' => Column::BIND_PARAM_INT,
            'email' => Column::BIND_PARAM_STR,
            'password' => Column::BIND_PARAM_STR,
            'created' => Column::BIND_PARAM_INT,
        ),

        //Fields that must be ignored from INSERT SQL statements
        MetaData::MODELS_AUTOMATIC_DEFAULT_INSERT => array(
            'id' => true
        ),
    );
}
```

Phalcon have a way to convert automatically sql types to php types? 
Thanks.

Comment: And what exactly doesn't work and how do you see that?

Comment: For example, if u load a model $user = User::findFirst(1), when u access to property $user->id its return a (string) "1"

Comment: I get always correct datatypes back with postgresql and phalcon 1.2.4. What Database are you on? Did you make any non-standard settings? Did your double-check your DB fields for int type?

Answer (score 2):

if you are using Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql as your adapter, Integers are returned as strings in PDO by default

to return the right types you need to setup the appropriate options for your adapter,
you need to set 
`ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` and `ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES` to `false`

you need to change your Adapter code in your config or service file as your setup like this

```
return new Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql([
    'host' => 'DATABASE_HOST',
    'username' => 'USERNAME',
    'password' => 'PASSWORD',
    'dbname' => 'DATABASE_NAME',
    'options' => array(
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
        PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES => false,
    )
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is important to say that you need the native mysql driver. Otherwise the options don't affect.

```
sudo apt-get purge php5-mysql
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
```